# set/remove default title in pdf displayed through header in php

Tags: php, header

I have a pdf file

i am displaying pdf like this

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');          
header('Content-Disposition: inline;  filename="' . $pdf . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
echo file_get_contents($pdf);
```

but in title of page  i am getting a last part of url

if url is `http://example.com/some`
title of browser will be `some`

can i change that title or remove it?

NB:I dont want to use iframe

Comment: No it can't be changed programmatically, but you can make the last part of the url a wildcard for the filename using rewrites

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for idea that works